# Image loading problems in titanium appcelerator

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules, titanium-android

I am developing a image gallery application using titanium android. The image view is used to view the images. But my problem is first time the images load properly. When I am using the app long time the the app use more cache memory as well as the image is not loading. The code is below

```
var SelfieImageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  width : '100%',
  height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
  image : 'http://mydomain.com/image1.png' ,
  defaultImage : '/images/Default-Back-Ground--Advertisements.png',
  bottom : 3,
  Index : FollowingFeedStartIndex,
 });
```

Comment: Add some code example showing what you've done and where is an issue.

Comment: var SelfieImageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  width : '100%',
  height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
  image : 'http://mydomain.com/image1.png' ,
  defaultImage : '/images/Default-Back-Ground--Advertisements.png',
  bottom : 3,
  Index : FollowingFeedStartIndex,
 });

Comment: there is a memory leak in your application which then makes it impossible to load the images

Comment: How to know memory leak of my application....